Movie about doctor selling the test tube baby fetus by cloning to many couples
I want to find this movie out. I don't remember much of the plot. But I'll write as far as I can remember. This is a movie about cloning.I watched this 10 or 12 years back.
A couple who couldn't consume a child normally goes to a doctor and they get a test-tube baby. When that kid grows up to 8 or 10 years he gets a disease and dies. One day after the death of kid mom sees a kid exactly looks like her kid, kind of about the same age, riding bicycle like their kid. Eventually they kind of get to know the parents and they learn that the kid has born in the same hospital where they went to consult. Eventually they find more kids and finally they got to know the doctor has kept their fetus and he's sold it to each couple they found by cloning. Near the end of the movie all the kids and their parents gather to the original parent's house. There are more than 5 cloned kids
Can anyone help me to find this movie for me?

Possibly Cloned with Elizabeth Perkins and Bradley Whitford from 1997:

In the year 2008, a married couple is distraught over losing their 8 year old son in a boating accident. However, when the mother suddenly sees another child who looks identical to her dead child, the Mother investigates the fertility clinic who aided her with her pregnancy and discovers that they cloned her child in an experiment dubbed "Baby 2000". She also discovers that they still have the genes to develop another child for them and faces the question of whether the couple wants another identical child.

Turns out at least 5 other families are raising an identical child. Here's a clip from the film:




You are a movie encyclopedia. Thanks mate. i just downloaded it and checked, yes this is the movie. Many thanks again for your help.
